# HAproxy: digest authentication

Tags: haproxy

We have setup a loadbalancer to balance 2 servers. The config looks like this:

```
global
    maxconn 40960
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    #option redispatch
    timeout client 10s
    timeout server 10s
    timeout connect 4s
    maxconn 40960

listen webpool lbIP:80
    mode http
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect
    balance roundrobin
    server slave1 slave1IP:80 cookie A check port 8981
    server slave2 slave2IP:80 cookie B check port 8982
```

The servers slave1 and slave2 needs digest authentication. When the client
sends a request the first request is balanced to slave1. This returns a 401: Unauthorized.
The second request is balanced to slave2 and will succeed, it returns a 200: OK. The problem is
that the authentication always happens on slave1 and the the response always came from slave2. I want
both requests(authentication and returning data) into one connection/slave.

Is it possible to configure this in HAproxy?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you can try using a different balancing algorithm `balance source` instead of roundrobin. Using this algorithm, all the requests from the same IP will go the same backend server (unless that server is down). This can distribute the load between your backend servers evenly depending on your clients IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, i tried that before. The problem is the requests came from 1 client/website. When i use "balance source" it will only use slave1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done quite simply.

```
balance uri
```

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4.2-balance

> **uri**
>   This algorithm hashes either the left part of the URI (before
>   the question mark) or the whole URI (if the "whole" parameter
>   is present) and divides the hash value by the total weight of
>   the running servers. The result designates which server will
>   receive the request. This ensures that the same URI will
>   always be directed to the same server as long as no server
>   goes up or down. This is used with proxy caches and
>   anti-virus proxies in order to maximize the cache hit rate.
>   Note that this algorithm may only be used in an HTTP backend.
>   This algorithm is static by default, which means that
>   changing a server's weight on the fly will have no effect,
>   but this can be changed using "hash-type".
>   This algorithm supports two optional parameters "len" and
>   "depth", both followed by a positive integer number. These
>   options may be helpful when it is needed to balance servers
>   based on the beginning of the URI only. The "len" parameter
>   indicates that the algorithm should only consider that many
>   characters at the beginning of the URI to compute the hash.
>   Note that having "len" set to 1 rarely makes sense since most
>   URIs start with a leading "/".
>   The "depth" parameter indicates the maximum directory depth
>   to be used to compute the hash. One level is counted for each
>   slash in the request. If both parameters are specified, the
>   evaluation stops when either is reached.

The uri is always the same so the challenge is sent to the same backend. Hopefully most of your uri's are unique (i.e. have a user id) so this doesn't compromise the balancing.